# Public variable name in script does not match field display in inspector/editor

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, flappy-bird-clone

S0 I am following a Unity tutorial on YouTube.  It is a flappy bird clone.  Everything is going good but I ran into a piece of code that I just can't wrap my head around.  I have attached to images ( one of the unity inspector and the other is the script).

My question is that in line 8 of the `GameControl` script, a variable `gameOverText` is created of the type `GameObject`. Then on line 27 the `gameOverText.SetActive("true")` is called.  I don't see how unity ties the `gameOverText` variable to the `GameOverText` in the unity inspector.
I know I dragged the `GameOverText` from the Hierarchy to the Game Control. As you can see in the pic the `GameOverText` in the inspector is spelled differently than the "gameOverVariable" in the script.

I just do not see how it works.

[image]
[image]

Comment: I wonder if there's a way to get rid of this not only useless but hindering "feature". Reasons: 1 I personally have certain conventions for naming variables 2. it's always a thought process to do the names matching instead of just acknowledging. 3. take `FBIagent`, `CIAagent` etc. Not to mention 4. `input` and `Input` as distinct variables are both "translated" into `Input`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both `public GameObject gameOverText` and the field "Game Over Text" displayed in the Unity inspector refer to the same variable. When Unity displays variables in the inspector, it splits up the variable name by capital letters and then capitalizes the first letter of the first word if needed. (Presumably this is to make variables more human-readable.)

In this way, we can see that "gameOverText" => "Game Over Text"; when you drag a reference onto the "Game Over Text" field, you are in fact setting the value of the `gameOverText` variable.

Comment: Thank you.  It seems to make sense after I read your explanation a few times over.